# Tools to profile function execution times of a .NET program

Tags: .net, benchmarking, profiling

What tools are available to profile a .NET program by measuring function execution times and generating graphs to visualize the time spent at various points in the call graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/) and [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) are two very good commerical profilers.

A free option would be [ProfileSharp](http://www.softprodigy.net/), though I have had little luck with it.

Microsoft provides the [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=86CE6052-D7F4-4AEB-9B7A-94635BEEBDDA&displaylang=en) as well, which works well, but has fewer features.

Comment: @Gorgen: Nope - this post pre-dated VS 2010 and .NET 4.  However, higher end SKUs of VS include a very nice profiler, now.

Comment: ok, that is why they have stopped updating the product. unfortunately do I use the Express version, it is in reach of my budget. Any sugestions?

Comment: @Gorgen: I suspect this is because they market it commercially, plus the CLR 4's profiling entry points have changed a lot.  That being said, there are a few decent free profilers out there.  Try SlimTune: http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/  or EQUATEC:   http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Download.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It'll cost you but [Ants Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

[CLR Profiler](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MeasureTwiceCutOnceCLRProfiler20.aspx)

Comment: CLR Profiler is 404

Answer (score 0):

There is a free C# IDE [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) 3.1, which has integrated [profiler](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/siegfried_pammer/archive/2009/04/04/introducing-a-new-tool-in-sharpdevelop-the-profiler.aspx), and it is compatible with Visual Studio solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What's the goal? Do you just want to 1) See a nice call graph with times on it, or 2) Locate cost points to optimize to make your program faster?

If the answer is (2), and you don't mind something that's free, you can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773) gives an example of how to use it.